# Fibonacci Algorithm with ASP.NET MVC JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, fibonacci

As the title says, I am trying to build a function where the user puts in an integer and gets an JavaScript alert if it's an Fibonacci number or not without hard-codeing, I have tried this so far and it works, but is there not an algoritm that can make all Fibonacci numbers instead of these selected ones?

Code:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Models;

namespace Andre_Kordasti___Programmeringsuppgift.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

     public ActionResult Fibonacci()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Fibonacci</h2>

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="fibonacciTextbox" id="fibonacciTextbox" />
<br />
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fibonacciFunction()">Sök</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
  function fibonacciFunction()
{
    var num = document.getElementById('fibonacciTextbox').value

    function isFibonacci(num)
    {
        var first = 0;
        var second = 1;
        var third = first + second;

        if (num === first)
        {
            return true;
            alert('Fibonacci Number!')
        }

        while (third <= num)
        {
            if (third === num)
            {
                alert('Fibonacci Number!')
                return true;
            }

            first = second;
            second = third;
            third = first + second;
        }

        alert('Not Fibonacci Number!')

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will find the fibonacci sequence just by sum the two previous numbers. 0, 1, *1*, 2, *3*, *5*, *8*, *13*, *21*, *34*, ...

Comment: You can create a function that recursively calls itself.

Comment: I edited the code, but it still does not work, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fibonacci sequence is the combination of the previous two numbers.  You can calculate it up to your number and if it is a part of that sequence then it is:

```
function isFibonacci (num){
  var first = 0;
  var second = 1; 
  var third = first + second;

  if(num === first){return true;}    

  while(third <= num)
  {
    if(third === num )
    {
       return true;
    }

    first = second;
    second = third; 
    third = first + second;
  }

   return false;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/04m4t9av/1/

Comment: So I did this and it did not work, I edited my JavaScript code, look below please, what did I do wrong?

Comment: @AndreKoroshKordasti. Change `var num = document.getElementById('fibonacciTextbox').value` to `var num = +document.getElementById('fibonacciTextbox').value;` and call the function to be executed: `isFibonacci(num);` at the end

Answer (score 4):

A fibonacci number can be determined by checking if the result of (5*n*n + 4) or (5*n*n - 4) or both are a perfect square.

```
function isFibonacci(num) {
    return isPerfectSquare(5*num*num + 4) || isPerfectSquare(5*num*num - 4);
}

function isPerfectSquare(n) {
    return Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
}
```

NOTE: Although there are ways to do this by either doing a recursive function or creating a loop, these methods would prove inefficient for large numbers.

Comment: A really nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Recursively find Fibonacci series-

```
var recursive = function(n) {
if(n <= 2) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return this.recursive(n - 1) + this.recursive(n - 2);
}
};
```